# searching an array of values with mongoDB

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I have a collection which contains only 1 document:

```
events: ['some event', 'another one', 'and another'];
```

how can I perform a search against this so if the search parameter was "som", the docs returned would be "some event".

Currently I have the following:

```
var collection = db.collection('suggestions');
collection.ensureIndex({events: "text"}, function(){});

collection.find({ $text: { $search: term } }).toArray(function(err, docs){
    if(err){
        console.log(err);
    }else{
        res.send(docs);
    }
});
```

where term is the search term - but this always returns an empty array [].

Can this be done with mongoDB?

Comment: `$text` is a full-text search. It searches over the tokens in your input text (with word stemming, so that `{$text: {$search: 'events'}}` would actually find something, even if the word your document *actually* contains is `'event'`). It depends on the value of `term` and the value of `default_language` of the index (or `$language` parameter of the search) what the result will look like. Maybe you didn't actually want to use a `$text` search?

Answer (score 1):

I think that searching a part of the word would require using `regex` queries, since text indexes, however very useful, as far as I know may only serve to find whole words.

You might find a part of the word using the following query :

```
var collection = db.collection('suggestions');
collection.ensureIndex({events: 1}, function(){});

var query = { events: new RegExp( term ) };

collection.find(query).toArray(function(err, docs){
    if(err){
        console.log(err);
    }else{
        res.send(docs);
    }
});
```

In the above there is also multi-key index created on events array (as an option for consideration).

I hope it helps at least slightly.

Comment: `'/' + term + '/'` does not construct a regex.

Comment: `new RegExp(term)` is not safe, because `term` can contain special characters. The term must be quoted, see this answer. http://stackoverflow.com/a/2593661/18771